# how to remove ezoic script

Tags: javascript, html, adsense

I want to remove ezoic script from my WordPress website. This is the part of the code which has to be removed
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9VJjj.png)

Comment: use a file editor, remove the lines, upload the result - what's the issue?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: If you are unable to remove the script on your own, double check that your site is no longer integrated with Ezoic. Or you could reach out to their support at support@ezoic.com